# Не открывается конфигурационное activity у виджета android

Tags: java, android, виджет

Всем привет:)

Короче говоря начал учить андроид виджеты, встала задача конфигурировать виджет при его создании. Нашел урок (http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/198-urok-118-vidzhety-konfiguratsionnyj-ekran-obnovlenie.html) делаю все по уроку, но активити не вылетает, хотя виджет создается. Вот манифест, не могу вьехать что не так ? Спасибо :)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ru.andrevv.autogrib">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name=".Widget" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configure=".ConfigActivity"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.pinger.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_metadata" />
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".ConfigActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

widget_metadata.xml

```
<appwidget-provider
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:minHeight="110dp"
android:minWidth="250dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="2400000">
android:configure="ru.andrevv.autogrib.ConfigActivity"</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: ну а сам xml/widget_metadata покажите

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei , обновил пост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. 
Ошибка в widget_metadata.xml. 
Правильный код:

```
<appwidget-provider
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:minHeight="110dp"
android:minWidth="250dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="2400000"
android:configure="ru.andrevv.autogrib.ConfigActivity"></appwidget-provider>
```